# Custom MVC HTMLHelpers in razor VB.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, html-helper

I have the following custom helper:

```
        <Extension> _
    Public Function ActionLinkAuthorized(htmlHelper As HtmlHelper, linkText As String, actionName As String, controllerName As String, routeValues As RouteValueDictionary, htmlAttributes As IDictionary(Of String, Object)) As MvcHtmlString
        If (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator")) Then
            Return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes)
        Else
            Return MvcHtmlString.Empty
        End If
    End Function
```

This can be seen fine in my razor view and am attempting to use it as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLinkAuthorized("Edit", "Edit", "Account", New With {.id = currentItem.Id}, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "btn btn-warning", .title = "Edit"})
```

But I am getting the following error when running my application:

> Value of type ' (line 193)' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary'.

I'm completely new to VB.NET and not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the routeValues as an Object, not as a RouteValueDictionary. Change your html helper to this:

```
<Extension> _
Public Function ActionLinkAuthorized(htmlHelper As HtmlHelper, linkText As String, actionName As String, controllerName As String, routeValues As Object, htmlAttributes As Object) As MvcHtmlString
    If (Roles.IsUserInRole("Administrator")) Then
        Return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes)
    Else
        Return MvcHtmlString.Empty
    End If
End Function
```

Also, you don't need to specify the argument name, when calling the html helper in your View. Use this:

```
@Html.ActionLinkAuthorized("Edit", "Edit", "Account", New With {.id = currentItem.Id}, New With {.class = "btn btn-warning", .title = "Edit"})
```